# best way to use viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a working viewpager example using code I got from a tutorial. The tutorial was written by Lauren Darcey and Shane Conder who are apparently experts (I am new to Android). The code is pasted below.  What this code is doing is inflating (ahead) and destroying (behind) as the user swipes horizontally.  There are only 5 pages. It seems that it would be much smarter to inflate them all and then let the user do all the swiping with no inflation/destruction going on.  Just like it were one big wide page (such as the Panarama and Pivot controls in Windows Phone 7).

Also, this code blows if one of the pages has a google map on it.  It blows on the second inflation (don't know why yet) and this wouldn't happen if they were just all inflated once.

Is there a reason why it has to be done this way?  Are there any examples available on doing the way I suggest?
Thanks,
Gary Blakely

```
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.farleft;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.left;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.middle;
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.right;
            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.farright;
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) to load all off-screen tabs. Just set it to `4` (that's 5 total, minus 1 visible) by doing `((ViewPager) collection).setOffscreenPageLimit(4);` or `((ViewPager) collection).setOffscreenPageLimit(getCount() - 1);`.

Keep in mind the memory implications of this; having everything loaded will run down the device's RAM if you're not careful.

Comment: Eric, That worked so well!  It inflates each page once and scrolling is fast and smooth.  After that the instantiateItem never gets called again.  thanks.

Comment: "Just set it to 4 (that's 5 total, minus 1 visible)" is not correct. If the number is set to 4, 9 pages will be loaded if the pages are enough, because ViewPager will retain 4 pages at either side of the current page. See the document  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit\(int\)

Comment: @Leoguo Yes, it is correct. There are only 5 total pages. Loading 9 doesn't make sense; there are not 9 pages to load. Instead, the OS loads *all* the `ViewPager`'s pages (except the current, which is stored as soon as you change page) into memory so that none of them are ever recreated.

Comment: @Eric Yes, you are right. I misunderstood you answer because I didn't read the question carefully.